# notify() not working in Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

Why I can't get notification from `reader` in this code:

```
public class ThreadMain {
    public Thread reader;
    private class SerialReader implements Runnable 
        {
        public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                Thread.sleep(3000);

                synchronized(this)
                    {
                    System.out.println("notifying");
                    notify();
                    }
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }

    ThreadMain()
    {
    reader = (new Thread (new SerialReader())   );
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    ThreadMain d= new ThreadMain();    
    d.reader.start();
        synchronized(d)
        {
            try
            {    
            d.wait();
            System.out.println("got notify");
            } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

        }

    }
}
```

I have just line `notifying` in output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `notify` and the `wait` do not use the same monitor so there is no chance they will "talk" to each other.

One simple fix is to use the reader as a monitor in your main:

```
synchronized (d.reader) {
    try {
        d.reader.wait();
        System.out.println("got notify");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `wait()` and `notify()` should be under same monitor. Currently `notify` In `SerialReader` under monitor `this` and `wait` under monitor `d` what is `ThreadMain`.

Btw one advice use `notifyAll()` instead `notify()`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your Code.

As suggested by others . You need to take the same lock for using notify and wait. You are using different Objects for waiting and notifying

There is another problem with your code even if you use correct monitor/locks.The problem is called Missed Notifications, i.e. your SerialReader thread can complete before your Mainthread executes its wait() method, this will result in infinite sleep of Mainthread.

Solution for both the above problem is to use a latch . try CountDownLatch See below

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class MyClass{

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public MyClass(){

}

public void a() {
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("A: I am going to sleep");
            System.out.println("A: I slept one full day. Feels great.");
            System.out.println("A: Hey B, wake up!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }).start();
}

public void b() {
    new  Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public  void run() {
            System.out.println("B: I am  going to sleep. A, please wake me up.");
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("B: Thank you A for waking me up!");
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    obj.a();
    obj.b();
}
```

The above code s from a my answer to  similar question